# 'Sign in to iCloud' pop-up won't stop popping up on my iPad

Tags: icloud

This is obviously a common problem but even after following the 're-boot' advice I can't get rid of it.  I can't sign in to iCloud because that e-mail address no longer exists and I can't receive the reset e-mail; the 'forgotten password' system rejects my password, my date of birth and my favourite band - all of which are well known to me.  Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I would recommend you visit an Apple store if it's in the neightbourhood or call them directly with your problem. This platform cannot help you with this deeper problem unfortunately, as it needs most likely to be reset by Apple itself.

Answer (score 2):

The workable solution (until you get to the Apple store, that is):

Step 1. enter the wrong password and press done until you are presented with the option to reset.

Step 2. press reset and wait until safari is opened.

Step 3. double-click the home button to get the list of opened apps.

Step 4. kill all of the opened apps including the reset password page.

Your iPhone will work until the next restart.

Answer (score 2):

The answer below, given by [randers4](https://discussions.apple.com/people/randers4) on [Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25894782#25894782), worked for me on my iPad.

> To change the iCloud ID you have to go to Settings>iCloud, tap Delete Account, provide the password for the old ID when prompted to turn off Find My iDevice, then sign back in with the ID you wish to use.
>
> When you do this you may find that the password for your old ID isn't accepted.  If this should happen, and if your old ID is an earlier version of your current ID, you need to temporarily recreate your old ID by going to https://appleid.apple.com, click Manage my Apple ID and sign in with your currentiCloud ID.  Click edit next to the primary email account, change it back to your old email address and save the change.  Then edit the name of the account to change it back to your old email address.  You can now use your current password to turn off Find My iDevice on your devices, even though they prompt you for the password for your old account ID. Then save any photo stream photos that you wish to keep to your camera roll.
>
> When finished go to Settings>iCloud, tap Delete Account and choose Delete from My iDevice when prompted (your iCloud data will still be in iCloud).  Next, go back to https://appleid.apple.com and change your primary email address and iCloud ID name back to the way it was.  Now you can go to Settings>iCloud and sign in with your current iCloud ID and password.

Answer (score 2):

This happened on my 5s. Steps taken:

1. Click ok when Sign in prompt appears
2. Select reset password
3. When reset screen appears push the home button. (Don't reset password)

This stopped the pop-up problem.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thks

Answer (score 0):

If you time it in betweet the pop up you can hit settings then wi-fi, once your ipad can get online your password will work and the pop up will stop. You do have to time it by hitting settings and wi-fi inbetween the pop up. It took me about 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

If you already connected to a Wifi, then go to **Settings > Wi-Fi** and tap on **Forget This Network**. This worked for me.